# Search a particular string in a vector(Octave)

Tags: octave, string-matching

I am trying to find a string in a vector.
For Eg:query = "ab" in vector = ["ab", "cd", "abc", "cab"]

The problem is: It is giving all the indices which have string "ab" when I use the function strfind(vector,query). In this case "ab" including "abc" and "cab". But i only want the index of "ab" not others.
Is there any specific function for this in Octave?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is on your syntax. When you do `vector = ["ab", "cd", "abc", "cab"]`,  you are not creating a vector of those multiple strings, you are concatenating them into a single string. What you should do is create a cell array of strings:

```
vector = {"ab", "cd", "abc", "cab"};
```

And then you can do:

```
octave-cli-3.8.2>  strcmp (vector, "ab")
ans =

   1   0   0   0
```

Many other functions will work correctly with cell array of strings, including `strfind` which in this cases gives you the indices on each cell where the string "ab" stars:

```
octave-cli-3.8.2> strfind (vector, "ab")
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [1,2] = [](0x0)
  [1,3] =  1
  [1,4] =  2
}
```

Comment: this is fine. But can you please tell me like how to append an element in this cell. Is there any inbuilt function?

Comment: Also if there are multiple matches or you're searching for multiple strings have a look at the `ismember` function. With regards to appending to the matrix you can do this: vector{end+1} = 'new string'. Have a look at [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620636/how-to-use-cell-arrays-in-matlab/25621199#25621199) for more details.