# MATLAB: create a list/cell array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

```
data = {};
data(1) = 'hello';
```

gives this error `Conversion to cell from char is not possible.`

my strings are created inside a loop and they are of various lengths. How do I store them in a `cell array` or `list`?

Comment: `data{1} = 'hello'`. Use curly braces to refer to the _content_ of a cell

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes! It works. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done. I've expanded the explanation a little

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use cell arrays in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620636/how-to-use-cell-arrays-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly braces to refer to the *contents* of a cell:

```
data{1} = 'hello'; %// assign a string as contents of the cell
```

The notation `data(1)` refers to the cell itself, not to its contents. So you could also use (but it's unnecessarily cumbersome here):

```
data(1) = {'hello'}; %// assign a cell to a cell
```

More information about indexing into cell arrays can be found [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the syntax you want is the following:

```
data = {};
data{1} = 'hello';
```