# How to store results created into a cell array during a multiple for loop into a 3d array? In Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cell-array

In Matlab, at the end of three different for loops (for a=1:240,b=1:5 and c=1:3), I generate a {1,3} cell array where each cell contains a (1,5) array that reports only the last result of the 240 iterations. 
How can I generate, apart of this cell array, a (240,5,3) 3d array that stores the result of each iteration? 
Or, equivalently, a cell array that stores again the information and then convert it into a (240,5,3) 3d array?

Comment: Please post some example data (input and worked output). Also read this for how to index cell arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25621199/1011724

Comment: Yes you're rigth. Suppose I have:

a=240;
b=5;
c=3;

A {c}= cell (1,b)

for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        for k=1:c
            
            A{c}(b)= %assignment
            
        end
    end
end

where %assignment is a series of operation through a,b,c. Now, at the end of this loop I obtain only A{c}(b), whereas I would like to obtain also a A (a,b,c) with the partial result of every single iteration on a,b,c.

Comment: Please put the code from your comment in your actual question, it's too hard to read in a commen

Comment: This question is not clear. Why are only the last results stored? Why a {1,3} cell? What is exactly stored, a scalar? If so the answer becomes very simple, but the question is still very complex and probably won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The code would be along the lines of:

```
%// Size of the problem
Na = 240;
Nb = 5;
Nc = 3;

%// Allocate empty cell array
result = cell(Na, Nb, Nc);

%// Loop
for a = 1:Na
        for b = 1:Nb
                for c = 1:Nc
                        %// Here is the code for computing the
                        %// result x of the last iteration.

                        result{a,b,c} = x;
                end;
        end;
end;
```