# Matlab loop to assign rows to cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, row, cell

I have a big cell array `A=cell(a,b,c,d)` and a row vector `B` with dimensions `1`-by-`b`.

I want to build a loop in MATLAB that does the following:

```
for i=1:n
   B = Calculate_row(input1,input2) %this is a function that creates my B row
   A{a,:,c,i} =  B(:)
end
```

anyway if I try to do `A{a,:,c} = B(:)` I receive the following error:

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were b results.

And if I try to do `A(a,:,c) = B(:)` I receive the following error:

> Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Is there a way to do this? (I know a less elegant way that probably works would be to assign each value to the cell separately, but I would prefer not to do it).

Comment: You probably just want this `A(a,:,c) = {B(:)}`. However, the way you call `Calculate_row` (if that is indeed how you are calling it) is really bad practice. Never call a script from another script, make sure you only call functions. Adapt `Calculate_row` to be a function that might look something like `B = Calculate_row(input1, input2,...)`

Comment: Did you miss out something? You assign it in a loop but you are not using `i` as an index somewhere in the assignment - furthermore `A` has 4 dimensions, but you are only giving 3 dimensions in the assignment. Did you want to do this `A{a,:,c,i} =  B(:)`? (just guessing). Please give a value for the 4th dimension and try the assignment again :-)

Comment: Also have a look here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html -> Depending on your data you might not even need Cells, I don't know. But if not required, then rather don't use it as it makes things much more complex :-)

Comment: Also pretty nicely explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9055336/701049 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make `B` a cell array and then take advantage of [comma-separated-lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
B_cell = num2cell(B);
[A{a,:,c}] = B_cell{:}    %// or [A{a,:,c,i}] = B_cell{:} if tim's comment is correct
```

Have a look at Loren Shure's article [Deal or No Deal](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/24/deal-or-no-deal/) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621199/1011724) for more.

The problem with your syntax, `A{a,:,c} =  B(:)`, is that the RHS (i.e. `B(:)`) is just one single matrix whereas the LHS is a comma-separated-list of `b` results. So you are basically requesting that `1` output be assigned to `b` variables and MATLAB doesn't like that, also hence the error message.

The problem with `A(a,:,c) = B(:)` is that indexing a cell array with `()` returns a cell array and you can't just assign a matrix (i.e. `B(:)`) to a cell array hence you second error.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I did as you suggested me but this way I still receive an error. When I type [A({1,:,1,1}] = B_Cell{:} I receive the error [A({1,:,1,1}] = B_Cell{:}
       ↑
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator. With the arrow pointing at the" : ".

Comment: Oh god I did not see it, my apologies, now it works. Thank you